# How to divide a file into parts and assign it (multiword parts)?

Tags: java, string

Ex#1. 1 AM Roset Malin 18 19

Ex#2. 2 PM Margie 20 21

If you did something like for Ex#1...

```
int a = scanner.nextInt() << 1
String b = scanner.next() << AM
String name = scanner.next() << Roset //Malin will not be shown here
String c = scanner.nextInt() << 18
```

**What if you wanted to have "Roset Malin" in a single variable AND still work correctly for Ex#2, where there is no two part name?**

I can't seem to find a way to do this. And before people asks, I'm not familiar with tokenizers, buffreaders (??) and such. Only have used scanners.

Comment: After the first number, keep reading until you encounter the second number.

Comment: If you're not familiar with something, get familiar with it. You can't just go "oops i only know how to use scanners" - it's not possible with a scanner. Deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed, names can be a real issue when retrieving **Space** delimited data since a name can contain one or more words, for example:

```
Dr. Steven Jon Parker III
```

Even perhaps no name at all which may or may not need to be considered.

I think an easy solution would be to use the [**Scanner.nextLine()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method instead of the [**Scanner.next()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method and then ***split*** the incoming file line with the [**String.split()**](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-split) method. In my opinion this then gives you easier control of the read data in this case.

The code example below utilizes the aforementioned **Scanner.nextLine()** and **String.split()** methods. Of course everything is enclosed within a **while** loop code block so as to iterate through the entire file. The condition for the **while** loop utilizes the [**Scanner.hasNextLine()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm) method which returns boolean ***true*** if there is another line in the input of the scanner object.

You will also notice that there are [**Regular Expressions**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) used within the code. These are simple expressions an I'll explain what they do now:

> **Expression used in the *String.split()* method - "\\s+":**

The **String.split()** method splits it's respective string into a [One Dimensional (1D) String Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) based on the supplied delimiter to the method which in this case is a white-space delimiter. The **"\\s"** expression means a **single** white-space whereas the **"\\s+"** expression actually used means **one or more** white-spaces. Why *one or more*? Well, to basically handle typo's where an unintentional white-space **may** have been supplied during data entry and not removed before the data string was saved to file.

> **Expression used in the [*String.matches()*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm)
>   method - "\\d+":**

In the code below we also utilize the [**String.matches()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method to merely verify the fact that the string we are about to convert to integer with the [**Integer.parseInt()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method is indeed a string representation of a ***numerical*** value. If we try to pass a value to this method that contains a space or a alpha (non-numerical) character then the **Integer.parseInt()** method will throw a [**NumberFormatException**](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-faq-what-is-numberformatexception) and possibly halting code execution.

The **"\\d"** expression used in the ***String.matches()*** method means, does the respective string match a string representation of a single numerical digit. The **"\\d+"** expression actually used means, does the respective string match a string representation of ***one or more*** numerical digits and we already know why we want one or more digits.

As mentioned the ***String.matches()*** method is merely used to validate the fact that what we are about to pass to the ***Integer.parseInt()*** method is indeed a string numerical value but if it fails this validation then 0 is placed into it's respective int variable. We use a [**Ternary Operator**](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) to do this. A Ternary Operator (also sometimes called a *Conditional Operator*) is basically a shortened version of an **if/else** situation.

Here is the code. Yes...it looks like a lot but it's mostly comments which you can safely remove if you like:

```
// A try/catch is required in case the supplied 
// file could not be found.
try {
    // Try With Resources to auto close the Scanner object
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Data.txt"))) {
        // Iterate through the file line by line
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String strg = scanner.nextLine();
            // Skip past blank lines (if any) and Comment Lines
            // that start with a semicolon (;) (if any). We don't
            // want to process these.
            if (strg.trim().equals("") || strg.trim().startsWith(";")) {
                continue;
            }
            // Split the read in line into a String Array
            String[] parts = strg.split("\\s+");
            // Get the number from the current file data line. Ternary
            // is used here. If the data is found not to be numerical
            // then 0 is used.
            int number = parts[0].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) : 0;
            // Get the AM or PM from the current file data line
            String amPM = parts[1];

            // Get the name from the current file data line
            String name = "";  // Declare & initialize the name variable
            // Start from parts Array index 2 because we already used 0 & 1
            int i = 2; 
            // Get the Name regardless of its length...
            for (; i < parts.length; i++) {
                // If we hit an element that is a numerical value
                // then we know we hit the end of our name, so we get
                // out of this loop with the break statement.
                if (parts[i].matches("\\d+")) { break; }
                // Ternary used here to see if the name variable contains
                // anything. If it doesn't then just a word is appended to
                // the string held by the variable otherwise a whitespace
                // and the word is appended.
                name+= name.equals("") ? parts[i] : " " + parts[i];
            }
            // If it was found that there is no name supplied 
            // in the current file data line then we will make
            // the name hold the string of: "Unknown".
            if (name.trim().equals("")) {
                name = "Unknown";
            }

            // Get first value after the name. Ternary is used here. 
            // If the data is found not to be numerical then 0 is used.
            int valOne = parts[i].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(parts[i]) : 0;
            // Get second value after the name. Ternary is used here. 
            // If the data is found not to be numerical then 0 is used.
            int valTwo = parts[i + 1].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(parts[i + 1]) : 0;

            // Display variable contents to the Console Window.
            System.out.println("Number:\t" + number);
            System.out.println("AMPM:\t" + amPM);
            System.out.println("Name:\t" + name);
            System.out.println("Value1:\t" + valOne);
            System.out.println("Value2:\t" + valTwo);
            System.out.println("=====================");
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger("Get Data Test").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

This code has been tested against a data text file named Data.txt. This is what it contains:

```
1 AM Roset Malin 18 19
2 PM Margie 20 21
3 PM Dr. Steven Jon Parker III 18 19
4 AM  20 21
5 AM Jack B Black 20 21
```

Console Window Display:

```
Number: 1
AMPM:   AM
Name:   Roset Malin
Value1: 18
Value2: 19
=====================
Number: 2
AMPM:   PM
Name:   Margie
Value1: 20
Value2: 21
=====================
Number: 3
AMPM:   PM
Name:   Dr. Steven Jon Parker III
Value1: 18
Value2: 19
=====================
Number: 4
AMPM:   AM
Name:   Unknown
Value1: 20
Value2: 21
=====================
Number: 5
AMPM:   AM
Name:   Jack B Black
Value1: 20
Value2: 21
=====================
```